# Laravel как в миграции сделать поле с NULL?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Например я добавляю поле тип текст с именем 'desc', и как мне на этапе создания миграции в $table->text('desc'); это указать для него?

```
    /**
 * Run the migrations.
 */
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('status', 1);
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->text('desc');
    });
}
```

Здесь есть предложение, но оно уж совсем костыльное, не ужели нет возможности полностью описать все св-ва поля? [https://clck.ru/37yE9Q][1]

Comment: пробовали [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-modifiers) читать? `$t->text('field')->nullable()` вам там не встретилось? зы: не называйте поля ключевыми словами

Comment: Большое спасибо, я только начал изучение, искал но не нашел пока не ориентируюсь в документации..

Answer (score 1):

В файле (классе) миграции необходимо использовать метод nullable.
Таким образом поле с "nullable" будет автоматически получать значение null, если иное значение не будет передано для записи. В это поле возможно будет записать значение null.

Пример ниже:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('desc')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Если необходимо, чтобы поле всегда получало значение по умолчанию, то можно для поля использовать метод default('значение по умолчанию') по аналогии с методом nullable();

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].